# Values file not generated after building the app in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-authentication, google-authenticator

So I'm following the Firebase documentation on how to sign in using google authentication, I have been following every step and I added every dependency, but I encounteted an error in this piece of code:

```
// Configure Google Sign In
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build();

 mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

I'm getting an error in "default_web_client_id" where it should be generated in a values.xml file after I build my app, but nothing happens when I do that, I have no idea how to solve this as I'm new to android studio, any help will be appreciated Thank you!

Comment: Since you're using Java, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. It's a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will work for everyone but I commited my project to github, deleted it and then cloned it again, and that seems to work (maybe the gradle sync didn't work properly the first time), hope this helps everyone with the same issue!